# r creating documentation from multiple R files

Tags: r

I have a project with multiple .R files. They need to be run in order (output from one is input into the next, etc.). Each is standalone, expecting that the input it needs has been generated previously. I have an R file I call `automate.R` that sources each .R file in the correct order. Each .R file starts with some text with rmarkdown code like the following.

```
#' @title calculate nutrient requirements for SSP age group categories
#' @author Gerald C. Nelson, \email{nelson.gerald.c@@gmail.com}
#' @keywords utilities, IMPACT data, gdx
# Intro -------------------------------------------------------------------

# Copyright (C) 2015 - 2018 Gerald C. Nelson, except where noted
#' @description - This script calculates nutrient requirements for SSP age group categories
#' The source of the requirements is
#' @source \url{http://www.nal.usda.gov/fnic/DRI/DRI_Tables/recommended_intakes_individuals.pdf}
#' @include nutrientModFunctions.R
```

Eventually I might want to convert some of this to a package, but for now, how do I have lines with markdown tags from each script be combined into one documentation file? The entire project is available at https://github.com/GeraldCNelson/nutmod, in case anyone wants some specific R code.

Comment: not an answer but looking at that repo I would just convert the whole thing into a package. Your documentation comments are already pretty close to roxygen comments, and if you can shuffle through roxygen will be able to rapidly create your documentation with `devtools::document`. You can even then use `pkgdown` to turn the documentation into an easily hosted github page. I feel this would be comparable effort to figuring out a way to parse your rmarkdown and convert to documentation yourself

Comment: Check Hadley's R packages book http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/